# Vue component not showing or getting up in laravel 6.18.16

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

My vue component isn't showing up and I can't see where I went wrong, I change my include app.js script but still same issue. I'm running npm run dev and I've cleared my cache.

**My app.js**

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('all-product', require('./components/allProduct.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

**My selection vue file allProduct.vue**

```
<template>
<h1>hello</h1>
</template>
```

**my page where vue is supposed to show**

```
<div id="app">
      <all-product></all-product>
</div>
```

**my app.blade.php file Where I include js and css file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>        
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>{{config('app.name','LSAPP')}}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
        <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
       <style>        
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        @include('inc.navbar')        
            @yield('content')                        
    </body>
</html>
```

**getting console error**

```
app.js:38203 [Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #app
warn @ app.js:38203
app.js:38203 [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <AllProduct>
       <Root
```

**my package.json file**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.13",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.20.1",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
        "vue": "^2.5.17",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add to blade file this

`<script src="{{ mix('dist/js/app.js') }}"></script>`

Comment: Your app.js script will execute first before the #app div has been loaded.

Put your script in your <body> tag
`<div id="app"> </div>`